# Reading dictionary and child dictionary from plist

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios7, uitableview, plist

I have created a plist file that looks like this:

[image]

From this is am able to extract all plist info into an NSArray:

```
-(NSArray *)Topics
{
    if(!_Topics)
    {
        _Topics = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TopicData" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }
    return _Topics;
}
```

And use this array to load a tableview of TopicTitle's:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.Topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"TopicTitle"];
```

When a row in the table is selected, I am passing the dictionary named 'Questions' to the next ViewController like this:

```
NSDictionary *questions = [[self.Topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Questions"];
[self.detailViewController setQuestions:(questions)];
```

From here I want to loop through each 'Question' dictionary and load the 'QuestionText' and 'AnswerOne / Two...' strings into an array of objects by doing something like this:

```
TopicQuestions = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *ques in self.Questions)
{
    Question* q = [[Question alloc] init];
    q.Question = (NSString*)[ques objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerOne = (NSString*)[ques objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerTwo = (NSString*)[ques objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerThree = (NSString*)[ques objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerFour = (NSString*)[ques objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    [TopicQuestions addObject:q];
}
```

But the 'Questions' dictionary does not seem to have this data available, it knows there are 4 child objects, but does not have all the key - pair values of these objects:

[image]

So my question is how should I pass the 'Questions' dictionary to the next ViewController so that I will still be able to access the 'QuestionText' and 'AnswerOne / Two...' nodes?

Or is there a better way of reading the strings without looping through each 'Question' dictionary?

Comment: In your screenshot the ques object is a string, not a dictionary.  So there are not 4 items inside it.  I think you are iterating through the plist improperly.

Comment: I don't know why the ques object is a string, as you can see in the for loop it is declared as a Dictionary, 

I don't iterate through the plist - i put it into the Topics array straight from the file

Comment: In the local variables it doesn't matter what you declare a variable as, it will show what it actually is.  I can declare an NSString object as a UIView, that doesn't make it one.

Comment: ok, so it must be a string because it only contains the value of the dictionary ('Question', 'Question - 2', 'Question - 3', 'Question - 4') and not the child elements (QuestionText and Answer), how do i go about passing the 'Questions' dictionary so that it will keep all the elements of each of the 4 child 'Question' dictionaries?

Comment: Replace the call to `valueForKey:` with a call to `objectForKey:`. Does that help? You should not use `valueForKey:` unless you really want to use key-value coding.

Comment: @JamClerk Did you look at my answer?  It shows exactly how to do your last question...

Comment: tried changing it to ObjectForKey:
NSDictionary *questions = [[self.Topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Questions"];

but this did not work, ques is still a string

Comment: @JamClerk Look at the first line of my answer inside the for loop.  That is your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are getting the question dictionary properly.  In your screenshot the `ques` object is an NSString object, not an NSDictionary.  So getting `objectForKey` on the `NSString` object `ques` is not going to work (and really should crash your app).

Try this for loop:

```
for(NSString *ques in self.Questions)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.questions objectForKey:ques];
    Question* q = [[Question alloc] init];
    q.Question = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerOne = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerTwo = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerThree = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    q.AnswerFour = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"QuestionText"];
    [TopicQuestions addObject:q];
}
```

Comment: You should use `objectForKey:`. Only use `valueForKey:` when you actually need to make use of key-value coding features.

Comment: thanks Putz, this worked along with using objectForKey to get the origional 'questions' dictionary